# Mysql - Update certain Table_2 values depending on duplicate Table_1 values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables - Table_1 and Table_2.

They have identical columns - Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4(integer).

Table 2 has a row with the following values:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,0   ,0      (From Table_1)
```

Table_1 has duplicate values corresponding to Col1 and Col2.

For example:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,0   ,1      (From Table_1) 
2) a   ,b   ,1   ,0      (From Table_1)
3) a   ,b   ,0   ,0      (From Table_1)
```

There is a '1' for Col4 (Row 1) and a '1' for Col3(Row 2).

Whenever there is a 1 for any of the columns for the duplicates of a Table_2 row  in Table_1, apply the 1 for the corresponding column.

So the final values for Table_2 will be:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,1   ,1      (From Table_1)
```

I tried

```
UPDATE Table_2 JOIN
       Table_1 ur
       ON Table_1.Col1 = Table_2.Col1 and Table_1.Col2 = Table_2.Col2
    SET Table_2.Col3 = if(Table_1.Col3 = 1,1,Col3), Table_2.Col4 = if(Table_1.Col4 = 1,1,Col4)
```

But it gives me the following result:

```
   Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1) a   ,b   ,0   ,1      (From Table_1)
```

This means it is considering only the first match. How can I consider ALL THE MATCHES in Table_1?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag because you are using MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that your `update` works, given the ambiguity in the column names.  Try doing it with explicit table aliases:

```
UPDATE Table_2 JOIN
       Table_1 ur
       ON ur.Col1 = Table_2.Col1 and ur.Col2 = Table_2.Col2
    SET Col3 = if(ur.Col3 = 1, 1, Table_2.Col3),
        Col4 = if(ur.Col4 = 1, 1, Table_2.Col4);
```

Or, a simpler formulation (assuming the values are always 0 and 1):

```
UPDATE Table_2 JOIN
       Table_1 ur
       ON ur.Col1 = Table_2.Col1 and ur.Col2 = Table_2.Col2
    SET Col3 = greatest(ur.Col3, Table_2.Col3),
        Col4 = greatest(ur.Col4, Table_2.Col4);
```

EDIT:

Oh, I see, there are multiple rows in `Table_1` that could be used for updating.   Only one of the rows will be chosen (arbitrarily) for the update. In this case, you need to pre-aggregate the table.

```
UPDATE Table_2 JOIN
       (select col1, col2, max(col3) as col3, max(col4) as col4
        from Table_1
        group by col1, col2
       ) ur
       ON ur.Col1 = Table_2.Col1 and ur.Col2 = Table_2.Col2
    SET Col3 = greatest(ur.Col3, Table_2.Col3),
        Col4 = greatest(ur.Col4, Table_2.Col4);
```

Comment: Gordon, I tried the above statement, but it is giving me the same result as before.

Comment: @zenCoder . . . See the revised answer.  I had missed the key point in the question.

Comment: both the tables have about 1.5 million rows. Is there a way I can optimize your updated query? It has been about 7 hours since I started the query.

Comment: @zenCoder . . . An index on `Table_2(col1, col2)` might help.  You can also try an index on `Table_1(col1, col2)`, but I don't think MySQL will use it for the aggregation.